# How can i use git pull --rebase in git GUI

Tags: git, git-gui

I am using git GUI. How can I implement the git bash command `git pull --rebase`?

I am going to use this command before push.

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom command in git gui: `Tools -> Add`

You can then enter a command:

- name "Pull with Rebase"
- with the command `git pull --rebase`